# How do you change a junos device root password with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, juniper, junos-automation

I am completely new to Ansible and cannot find much documentation regarding changing the root password of a Juniper device. What is the framework to do something like this?

This is what I have so far but I am not confident it is correct.

```
---
- vars: 
  newPassword: "{{ newPassword }}"
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Update Root user's Password
    user: 
     name: root
     update_password: always 
     password: newPassword
```

Comment: Use the dedicated module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/junipernetworks/junos/junos_user_module.html#ansible-collections-junipernetworks-junos-junos-user-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good introduction regarding [Understanding the Ansible for Junos OS Collections, Roles, and Modules](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos-ansible/ansible/topics/concept/junos-ansible-modules-overview.html) with references to the [Ansible Collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html) [Junipernetworks.Junos](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/junipernetworks/junos/).

As already mentioned in a comment, modules for certain tasks are available including [Manage local user accounts on Juniper JUNOS devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/junipernetworks/junos/junos_user_module.html#examples).

```yaml
- name: Set user password
  junipernetworks.junos.junos_user:
    name: ansible
    role: super-user
    encrypted_password: "{{ 'my-password' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    state: present
```